# Understanding an example of M. L. Wage, W. G. Fleissner, and G. M. Reed

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

In [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1976-82-04/S0002-9904-1976-14150-X/S0002-9904-1976-14150-X.pdf) of M. L. Wage, W. G. Fleissner, and  G. M. Reed, the authors claimed that having a zeroset diagonal does not guarantee submetrizable by showing **Example 2**. However, the example is very obscure.

> The construction of Example 2 is done in a similar manner by considering Heath's "V" space defined on a Q-set.

**Could somebody help me to explain it?**

---

**Added by Arthur Fischer.** In

> Heath, R. W., *Screenability, pointwise paracompactness, and metrization of Moore spaces*, Canad. J. Math. 16 (1964), 763–770, [MR0166760](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=166760), [link](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1964-073-3)

Heath's "V" space is constructed as follows.

> Let $X = \{ \langle x , y \rangle \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} : y \geq 0 \}$ be the closed upper half-plane, and give it the topology generated by the following basic open neighbourhoods:
>
> - every $\langle x ,y \rangle \in X$ with $y > 0$ is isolated;
> - for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, given $n \geq 1$ the set $V_{x,n} = \{ \langle\, x+y , |y| \,\rangle : \frac{-1}{n} \leq y \leq \frac{1}{n} \}$ is a basic open neighbourhood of $\langle x , 0 \rangle$.

(Note that $V_{x,n}$ is a "$\mathsf{V}$" with vertex $\langle x,0 \rangle$, slopes $\pm 1$ and height $\frac 1n$.)

This is a pointwise paracompact Moore space which is not screenable.

Comment: Did you check in Heath's article [Screenability, pointwise paracompactness, and metrization of Moore spaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1964-073-3)?

Comment: It seems not work.

Comment: For completeness I've added the construction of Heath's "V" space to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction is given in much more detail in G.M. Reed, ‘On normality and countable paracompactness’, *Fundamenta Mathematicae*, Vol. $110$, Issue $2$, pp. $145-152$, freely available [here](https://eudml.org/doc/211203).